# How can i change address/ street format in customer form view (odoo 11)?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

please, i want to change the address format in customer form view odoo? how can i do that?.

I tried to change the code to XML but nothing changes!

```
<xpath expr="//div[@class='o_address_format']" position="replace">
                <div class="o_address_format">
                            <field name="street" placeholder="Street..." class="o_address_street"/>
                            <field name="city" placeholder="City" class="o_address_city"/>
                            <field name="state_id" class="o_address_state" placeholder="State" options='{"no_open": True}'/>
                            <field name="zip" placeholder="Code postal"/>
                            <field name="country_id" placeholder="Country" class="o_address_country" options='{"no_open": True, "no_create": True}'/>
                        </div>
            </xpath>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally there was another module that inherited the street field, so my code doesn't work; so the solution is to make the changes I wanted in the first module.

So my problem is solved